# express-api gets /inform post from localhost

Tags: api, rest, express, proxy, apache2

on my express rest-api I'm logging a /inform post every minute or something.

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 POST /inform 404 146 - 69.963 ms
::ffff:127.0.0.1 POST /inform 404 146 - 62.149 ms
::ffff:127.0.0.1 POST /inform 404 146 - 20.479 ms
```

I have configured apache2 proxy from api.domain.com:80 to localhost:8080 (which is my express-api) and everything else is working fine.

The system is Debian10 with node, apache2, php and so on:

```
node -v
v10.24.0

npm -v
7.6.0

php -v
PHP 7.3.27-1~deb10u1 (cli)

/usr/sbin/apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Server built:   2020-08-25T20:08:29
```

This has obviously something to do with the proxy, but I don't know what.
The Apache2-Config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName api.domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@api.domain.com

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
        KeepAlive Off

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        # certs here
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Can someone tell me where this is coming from?

Comment: I see the same thing. Do you have any Ubiquiti gear in your network? I'm thinking it might be an AP trying to contact its controller: https://jrjparks.github.io/unofficial-unifi-guide/protocols/inform.html

Comment: actually I am using the Unify Security Gateway at home. That must be it, thank you!

Comment: Then I'll post that as an answer. Would be nice if you could mark it as correct :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any Ubiquiti gear in your network, they may be trying to "phone home" to the Unify controller app, which runs on the same port. See jrjparks.github.io/unofficial-unifi-guide/protocols/inform.html

I had the same issue, and solved it by running my application on a different port that didn't get pinged by rogue network members.